# Adjust icon positioning when loading a new icon font

Tags: css

I just created my new icon set font, but when loading it, icons don't position correctly and have a smaller size than expected:

[image]

[image]

I tried to add to the general `.icon` class position:relative, as well as playing with line-height and font-size.

```
position: relative;
bottom: -4px;
```

**But this will only position things correctly in buttons, not in every element since each element has its own padding, line-height etc.**

¿Is there any fix / strategy to position all of them correctly? ¿Do I need to adjust the font instead of adjusting the CSS?

**CSS**

```
[class^="icon-"], [class*=" icon-"] {
  /* use !important to prevent issues with browser extensions that change fonts */
  font-family: 'icomoon' !important;
  speak: never;
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: normal;
  font-variant: normal;
  text-transform: none;
  line-height: 1;
  font-size: 1.3rem;
  position: relative;
  bottom: -4px;

  /* Better Font Rendering =========== */
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
}
```

Comment: Icon fonts (or svg icon sets) are by no means standardized. So if you're mixing or swapping icons from different libraries it's better to keep the original font file and override icon classes with additional style rules (So you're loading e.g icomoon.woff and icomoon2.woff). Besides I highly recommend using relative units like em to inherit the parent elements font-size.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
.parent {
  display: flex;
  align-items: baseline;
}
```

Comment: thanks but this means applying a new class to each element that contains icons which I prefer to avoid. Thank you

Comment: @Gibson Oh, I get what you mean now, I never ran into a similar problem because I don't use many icons to start with